# Is it possible to create another SSRS home folder

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

We are working on some reporting in sql server 2016 and the new standalone reporting services 2016  with power bi from Microsoft.

Some of our reporting user need not view every report we create.

We could create multiple folder in the *HOME* folder itself but I'm curious if anyone know ***if we can create another HOME folder for another user report***?

Comment: If you want to hide reports from users, set report level security. You should be able to hide reports from specific users in this way. Then you aren't copying and duplicating reports into different folders. But _first_ you need to consider define which groups should see what, then put them into a windows group then use that to assign security

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid 
When I only grant them access to the report folder which contain the reports (subfolder in home folder)
without grant access to the HOME--Manage Folder--Security, they will get the error 

"You are not allowed to view this folder. Contact your administrator to obtain the necessary permissions."

I think this maybe because they don't have access to the parent folder then they can't see the child folder(they have access to)